# call js function from address bar

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to call a js function from the address bar in the browser.
For example I have the following function

```
function doThis(url, id){//some code};
```

and I have the page on which I want to call that function from the address bar

```
http://mypage.com/index.html
```

I want to be able to call that function when adding

```
http://mypage.com/index.html?callFunction=doThis('/blabla/blaba.htm', 123312);
```

I tried with

```
if (!empty($_GET['doaction']) && $_GET['doaction'] == do1 ){echo '<script>alert("hello");</script>';}
```

but it just launches the alert window upon loading the page not when i try to call, it just launches it right away

```
http://mypage.com/index.html?doaction=do1
```

Any ideas on how to make this work would be much appreciated :)
Thanks

Comment: That is a huge XSS security hole. Do not do it.

Comment: like epascarello said dont do this...but if you do it anyway try quotation marks in your if clause `... == 'do1'`

Comment: this seems like a XY problem.. could you tell us exactly what are you trying to do? maybe there are better options like AJAX or domready methods...

Comment: I can use a factory pattern and php but that would be rewriting the code completely and the work put into it doesn't quite pay off, security is unimportant in this case, i just need to call a java function from the url regardless how, simple as that :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not wise to do that as it has big security issues but however if you want to do it. This can be easily done by:

assuming that you have got the code to be executed by querystring or posted data in variable **Code **

just write:

```
eval(Code);
```